# Why aren't these two expressions in cases aligned?

Tags: math-mode, cases

Why aren't these two expressions aligned? They have exactly same size.
[image]

Is it intended by default?
How can I make them aligned?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
$
H_K = 
\begin{cases}
x_1 H_{AB}+x_2 H_{BC}+x_3 H_{CA}, & (\text{A}, \varphi_1)\\
y_1 H_{AB}+y_2 H_{BC}+y_3 H_{CA}, &  (\text{B}, \varphi_2)\\

\end{cases}  
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: they are aligned on their left edge. you have not specified any other alignment point. x and y are not the same width so the expressions are not the same size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the problem is the different width of x and y, you probably want the alike terms in each row, that is, `H_{AB}` and similar, to be right aligned, so they're exactly one above the other. The slight difference in the space around the + signs will not be noticed.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
  H_k =
  \left\{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% like for cases
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% let TeX do the spacings
    \begin{array}{
      r 
      >{{}}c<{{}}
      r 
      >{{}}c<{{}}
      r 
      @{\quad}
      l
    }
    x_1 H_{AB} &+& x_2 H_{BC} &+& x_3 H_{CA}, & (\mathrm{A}, \varphi_1)\\
    y_1 H_{AB} &+& y_2 H_{BC} &+& y_3 H_{CA}, & (\mathrm{B}, \varphi_2)
    \end{array}
  \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Note `\mathrm`, not `\text`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As David Carlisle pointed out in the comments, `x` and `y` have different width thus the misalignment.

Since you are using `IEEEtran` document class, here's a simple fix to your problem

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
H_k = 
\left\{\IEEEstrut[4\jot][4\jot]\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{CCC'C}
x_1 H_{AB}&+x_2 H_{BC}&+x_3 H_{CA}, & (\text{A}, \varphi_1)\\
y_1 H_{AB}&+y_2 H_{BC}&+y_3 H_{CA}, & (\text{B}, \varphi_2)
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach, using the amsmath `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
  H_k =
  \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
      %        R & L              &              R & L
      x_1 H_{AB} &{} + x_2 H_{BC} &{} + x_3 H_{CA},& \quad (\text{A}, \varphi_1)\\
      y_1 H_{AB} &{} + y_2 H_{BC} &{} + y_3 H_{CA},& \quad (\text{B}, \varphi_2)
    \end{alignedat}
  \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Cases rendered with amsmath alignedat]

I've added in a `\quad` space after the aligned comma, since `alignedat` will just remove the space otherwise.

I also added curly braces between alignment characters and the plus (`&{} +`) because otherwise it eats the default whitespace, but try it without them and see how it sits for you.

*Edit:* By the amsmath User's Guide, the second argument to `alignedat` should be 2 instead of the previous 4:

> count the maximum number of &s in any row, add 1 and
> divide by 2

they render identically for me.

*Edit 2:* You can get more fine-grained alignment by putting in more align characters - the alignment goes

```
R&L & R&L
```

where `R` and `L` are right-aligned and left-aligned sections respectively. (This also demonstrates why there are 2 aligned columns for three `&` alignment characters, not 4).

In action:

```
\[
  H_k =
  \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{4}
      %        R & L     &          R & L     &          R & L     &                    R & L
      x_1 H_{AB} &{} + {}& x_2 H_{BC} &{} + {}& x_3 H_{CA},& \quad & (\text{A}, \varphi_1)&  \\
      y_1 H_{AB} &{} + {}& y_2 H_{BC} &{} + {}& y_3 H_{CA},&       & (\text{B}, \varphi_2)&
    \end{alignedat}
  \right.
\]
```

[image: Cases rendered in amsmath alignedat with more alignment]